# MediWiki, Access Control , A member of one group must be able to edit only the pages created by members of that group

Tags: mediawiki, role-based-access-control

In MediaWiki looking for following solution.
A member of one group must be able to edit only the pages created by members of that group.
A member of one group must not be able to edit the pages created by members of another group which this person is not a part of.

Comment: It can be implemented using "$wgRestrictionLevels"https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRestrictionLevels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
make following entry in LocalSetting.php

   $wgGroupPermissions['development']['edit'] = true;
   $wgGroupPermissions['development']['createpage'] = true;
   $wgGroupPermissions['development']['upload'] = true;
   $wgGroupPermissions['development']['move'] = true;
   $wgGroupPermissions['development']['protect'] = true;

   MediaWiki:Group-development(content: Development)
   MediaWiki:Group-development-member(content: Development)
   MediaWiki:Grouppage-development(content: Project:Development)


# add an additional protection level restricting edit/move/etc. to users with the "development" permission
   $wgRestrictionLevels[] = 'development-team'; 
# give the "development" permission to users in the "development-team" and "development" groups
   $wgGroupPermissions['development']['development-team'] = true;
# give the "development-team" permission to sysops (needed so sysops can apply this protection level to pages)
   $wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['development-team'] = true;
    
#It can be implemented using "$wgRestrictionLevels"mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRestrictionLevels
```